# GWT, disable autoclose MenuBar when clicking on MenuItem?

Tags: gwt, menuitem, menubar, auto-close

I want to if it is possible to disable the auto-close MenuBar when I click on a MenuItem?
I have several MenuItem that are like checkboxes, so I can check more than one MenuItem and don't want my menu close everytime I checked one.

Thanks.

Comment: I can't figure out how to prevent a MenuBar from closing when selecting an Item, or how to open a MenuBar programmatically. It seems like something that should be included though. You may just have to make your own "MenuBar" that uses [Popup Panels](http://google-web-toolkit.googlecode.com/svn/javadoc/2.3/com/google/gwt/user/client/ui/PopupPanel.html) as bad as that sounds.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

First, directly it's not possible because the popup-panel which displays the submenu is private in the MenuBar class.

Buuut, there is a way to do so ...

Simpley fetch the current MenuBar.java code out of googles code repository and include it in your eclipse gwt-project.

You don't have to change anything e.g. package deklaration or something. Just put your source in your project and it will simply replace the original MenuBar-class from the gwt-sdk during compilation (works also with hosted development mode).

Then you can simply set the property autoHide of the popup-Panel to false and the popup shouldn't disappear after clicking.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing same problem and I will share with you my solution:

1) Create new class MyMenuItemWithCheckBox that extends the MenuItem.
   In the constructor set element ID to (forexample) menuItemWIthCheckBox + Unique text.
   this.getElement().setId("menuItemWithCheckBox_" + menuItemLabel);

2) Create new class MyMenuBar that extends the MenuBar.
   Override the onBrowserEvent method by following:

```
Override
    public void onBrowserEvent(Event event) {
        if (DOM.eventGetType(event) == Event.ONCLICK && getSelectedItem().getElement().getId().contains("CheckBox")) {
            Scheduler.get().scheduleFinally(new Scheduler.ScheduledCommand() {
                @Override
                public void execute() {
                    getSelectedItem().getScheduledCommand().execute();
                }
            });

            event.stopPropagation();
        } else {
            super.onBrowserEvent(event);
        }
    }
```

Now scheduled command of MenuItem is always called, but in the case of your
menu checkBox item there is no close of a menubar.

I hope this help you, I spend more than day to create this solution. :-)

Answer (score -1):

You can set `hideOnClick` to false on the menuItems

See [here](http://www.sencha.com/forum/showthread.php?143456-Suppress-menu-hide-of-a-menu-button).

Comment: Does not apply to default GWT